# Joining entity objects by foreign key with Java Stream API

Tags: java, join, entity, java-stream

I am training for using Java Steam API and implemented what mentioned in title.
But I am dissatisfied with my code.

For example, there are three entity classes which is simple immutable bean.

**CODE:**

```
public class Country {
    private final Integer countryId; // PK, primary key
    private final String name;

    public Country(Integer countryId, String name) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // omitting getters
}

public class State {
    private final Integer stateId;   // PK
    private final Integer countryId; // FK, foreign key
    private final String name;

    public State(Integer stateId, Integer countryId, String name) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // omitting getters
}

public class City {
    private final Integer cityId;    // PK
    private final Integer stateId;   // FK
    private final String name;

    public City(Integer cityId, Integer stateId, String name) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // omitting getters
}
```

These entities relation is **one to many**, not many to many.

I want to create `Map<Country, Map<State, City>>` object from entity collections as
`Collection<Country>`, `Collection<State>` and `Collection<City>` using PK and FK relations.

My implementation is here.

**CODE:**

```
// entity collections
Set<Country> countries = Collections.singleton(new Country(1, "America"));
Set<State> states = Collections.singleton(new State(30, 1, "Wasington"));
Set<City> cities = Collections.singleton(new City(500, 30, "Wasington, D.C."));

// intermediate maps
Map<Integer, City> fkCityMap = cities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(City::getStateId, Function.identity()));
Map<Integer, State> fkStateMap = states.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(State::getCountryId, Function.identity()));
Map<Integer, Map<State, City>> fkStateCityMap = fkStateMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, entry -> Collections.singletonMap(
        entry.getValue(), fkCityMap.get(entry.getValue().getStateId()))));

// result
Map<Country, Map<State, City>> mapWhatIWant = countries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
        country -> fkStateCityMap.get(country.getCountryId())));
```

It works, but not elegant especially commented **"intermediate maps"** part, I think.
Is there better way to implement this?

---

**UPDATE**

There are [mistakes mentioned by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40535222/5109064).

1. The type what I want is `Map<Country, Map<State, Collection<City>>>`,
   not `Map<Country, Map<State, City>>`.
2. I misunderstood about Washington and Washington D.C.
   So, code commented **entity collections** is bad example.

Comment: First, you should rethink your actual task. Is there really a 1:1 mapping between `State` and `City`?

Comment: @Holger I am sorry,  I am not English speaker. This is wrong naming. I will update this later. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Holger Mapping between `State` and `City` is not 1:1. It is **one to many**. So, type what I want is `Map<Country, Map<State, Collection<City>>>` as mentioned your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way, you have defined your intermediate maps, i.e. `Map<Integer, City> fkCityMap`, mapping from *state id* to city, and `Map<Integer, State> fkStateMap`, mapping from *country id* to state, you are establishing the assumption that there can be only one `State` in a `Country` and exactly one `City` in a `State`, which indirectly also allows only one `City` in an entire `Country`.

Of course, you won’t notice as long as your test data consist only of exactly one `Country`, one `State` and one `City`. Even worse, even your intended result type `Map<Country, Map<State, City>>` works only if there is exactly one `City` per `State`. So not only your implementation is broken, even the task definition is.

Let’s redefine the result type as `Map<Country, Map<State, Set<City>>>`, to allow more than one `City` per `State`, so you can implement the operation as

```
Map<Country, Map<State, Set<City>>> mapThatYouWant = countries.stream()                
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), c->states.stream()
        .filter(s -> Objects.equals(s.getCountryId(), c.getCountryId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s->cities.stream()
            .filter(city -> Objects.equals(city.getStateId(), s.getStateId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())))));
```

but note that creating intermediate maps for looking up items might be actually more efficient than searching the sets linearly multiple times. You only have to care to create the right kind of maps.

```
Map<Integer,Country> countryById = countries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getCountryId, Function.identity()));
Map<Integer,Set<City>> citiesByStateId = cities.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(City::getStateId, Collectors.toSet()));

Map<Country, Map<State, Set<City>>> mapThatYouWant = states.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> countryById.get(s.getCountryId()),
        Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
            s -> citiesByStateId.getOrDefault(s.getStateId(), Collections.emptySet()))));
```

---

By the way, [Washington, D.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.) is not in the [state Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_(state)).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand what I mistook. Two codes you showed are both easy to read and clear what that code want to do. It is good example how to use `Optional` and `groupingBy`. I will study Java Stream API more and more with your comment. Thank you very much!